# Matlab loops dependent on each other and

Tags: matlab, loops, vectorization

Matlab loops dependent on each other and the inner loop has values that change with each iteration of the loop. How do I do this in matlab?

```
for i = 1:2:Max
C = [A(i+2)-A(i)]/2
for  k = i:1:i+2
A(k+1) = A(k) + C
end
end
```

As you can see the inner for loop has values that are changed so vectorization doesn't work.

Comment: Why is your code not working? What output are you expecting for what input? Create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Max=10;
A=zeros(1,Max+3);
A([1,2,3])=[3,7,2];
for i = 1:2:Max
    C = [A(i+2)-A(i)]/2;
    A(i+1:i+3) = A(i+0:i+2) + C;
end
disp(A)
```

Comment: Doesn't work because A is dependent on the previous A change inside the same iteration of the loop.

Comment: What doesn't work? The recursion came from your formula.